# How to post messages from website to twitter

Tags: html, css, twitter

I'm building an application where users post their tips on various topics on my website. From my website I want to be able to post the best write-up on twitter with a single click from my website.

Are there any tutorials that show how to implement this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is giving little to no information on what technologies you use. E.g. is it a plain HTML website, are you using a web framework? Did you try anything yourself already?

Automated tweet posting can be done with [Twitter's own API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api), which has various libraries in various languages to help you achieve what you want. Those libraries can be found [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tools-and-libraries/v2).

If you need help, please provide more information on what you're working with.